# Recreate grid with gradient css3

Tags: jquery, loops, gridview, gradient

I'm trying to generate a gradient that would have the same effect as the image below image Example:

Which is just one column.

This is the information I have:

```
ContainerWidth: 960px;    
GutterWidth:20px;         (GR + GL)
NumberOfColumns:16;       (C * 16)
ColumnWidth:40px          (C)
```

***Note: The above information is DYNAMIC, the user can change this information, and once the window is resized below the ContainerWidth, it's then set to 100%, hence why I need the percentage dynamic.***

I did try this with color stops and was successful, but it seemed way too overkill.

[image]

**EDIT** I posted the answer with the color stops, but the answer posted by Majky is definitely the correct way!

Comment: Why do you want percentages? And another thing I'm missing here is what are you trying to do with your calculations. Add some details please.

Comment: I have added a gradient example :)

Comment: In this case you should use image pattern. Its simpler solution. Also you are using it on `body` so when you resize browser window your background will be stretched. And next thing is that not all browsers are using webkit.

Comment: I know all of the above, however I should have mentioned that this will be dynamic, as in when the user changes options, the gradient would update. 

I would also be using the background-clip option to only fill the gradient within the compounds of the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are looking at creating a grid from a gradient with custom attributes, this is how I achieved this using sass/scss:

```
@mixin buildGridGradient($c1: #444, $c2: #111, $c3: #222, $gutter: $gutterWidth, $nc: $numberOfColumns, $c: $columnWidth) {
  $gr: ();
  $wgr: ();
  $halfGutter: $gutter / 2;
  $resetGutter: $halfGutter;
  $from:left;
  $to:right;

  @for $columns from 0 through $nc {

    @if $columns > 0 {
      $resetGutter: $gutter;
    }
    @if $columns != 16 {
      $gutterLeftStart :    strip-units(perc($resetGutter * $columns)) + strip-units(perc($c * $columns));
      $gutterLeftEnd :      $gutterLeftStart + strip-units(perc($halfGutter));
      $gridLeft :           $gutterLeftEnd;
      $gridRight :          $gridLeft + strip-units(perc($c));
      $gutterRightStart :   $gridRight;
      $gutterRightEnd :     $gutterRightStart + strip-units(perc($halfGutter));

      $gutterLeftStartWK : $gutterLeftStart / 100;
      $gutterLeftEndWK   : $gutterLeftEnd / 100;
      $gridLeftWK        : $gridLeft / 100;
      $gridRightWK       : $gridRight / 100;
      $gutterRightStartWK: $gutterRightStart / 100;
      $gutterRightEndWK  : $gutterRightEnd / 100;

      $wgr: join($wgr, unquote("color-stop(#{$gutterLeftStartWK}, green)"), comma);
      $wgr: join($wgr, unquote("color-stop(#{$gutterLeftEndWK}, green)"), comma);
      $wgr: join($wgr, unquote("color-stop(#{$gridLeftWK}, red)"), comma);
      $wgr: join($wgr, unquote("color-stop(#{$gridRightWK}, red)"), comma);
      $wgr: join($wgr, unquote("color-stop(#{$gutterRightStartWK}, green)"), comma);
      $wgr: join($wgr, unquote("color-stop(#{$gutterRightEndWK}, green)"), comma);

      $gr: join($gr, unquote("green #{$gutterLeftStart}%"), comma);
      $gr: join($gr, unquote("green #{$gutterLeftEnd}%"), comma);
      $gr: join($gr, unquote("red #{$gridLeft}%"), comma);
      $gr: join($gr, unquote("red #{$gridRight}%"), comma);
      $gr: join($gr, unquote("green #{$gutterRightStart}%"), comma);
      $gr: join($gr, unquote("green #{$gutterRightEnd}%"), comma);
    }
  }
  $prefixes: (-webkit-, -moz-, -ms-, -o-);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, #{$from} 50%, #{$to} 50%, #{$wgr});
  @each $prefix in $prefixes {
    background-image: #{$prefix}linear-gradient(#{$from}, #{$gr});
  }
}
```

The above mixin works brilliantly, although jsfiddle does support sass, but it seems it's either outdated, or doesn't accept some arguments, so I posted what the results was in the demo below.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/DRuSk/

Comment: I think this is doing exactly the same job as my example. Or I still didn't get the purpose of your work. But anyway great job up there!

Comment: Your code wont simulate the smaller columns on the left. Please take a closer look at your gradient on a div of the same size. Its not the same

Comment: Yes, but this could be easily done with `border-left` and `border-right` :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DRuSk/1/ I added your code with your suggestions, how do you define the columns though? I don't understand the gradient, I needs to match the gradient below it, your example is the top one.

Comment: If I can match it with that, i'd be happy, but I don't think it's possible, where did you get 80% 80% from? and why is it only 50px on the x, shouldn't it be 40px?

Comment: Sorry that i posted 50px example, it can be easily adjusted. Let me explain: 50px is width of wider and shorter stripe together. Then 80% is width of wider one - 40px and rest 20% is width of shorter - 10px. Adjusted to your data it should be 60px and 66.6666%. Also if you want left and right short stripes for example 10px then add border and reduce width to 940px (+20px border = exactly 960px). I added jsFiddle to my post and edited it to match your data. Check it out :) btw your example gives 41px and 19px stripes.

Comment: Yep thats because in gradients percentages are rounded too early.

Comment: The only problem I have with this example is that actually using the wqy you would does reduce the content size which is pretty bad, it needs to remain at 960px, so close though!

Comment: Updated my post :) as I told u before, CSS3 is very powerful, just do some research and think simply.

Comment: Do you mind me asking why percentages don't work the same? (unless me calculations are incorrect) 
http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/A3Z2L/2/

Comment: We should cleanup this question...its really big mess :) In this case you should use something like `linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 66.6666%, green 33.3333%)` because gradient size is calculated not from total width of element but based on width you set in background-size so that is taken as 100%. And personally I would use pixels, not percentages.

Comment: Oh okay, I had it all backwards! I need it to use percentages so that it's fluid when the container resizes! :)

Comment: Yep but the container will be set to 100% when the page size is less than 960px, sorry another thing I'll fix up in the question...

Answer (score 2):

Try this CSS3 stripes pattern. It should do what you are looking for.

**Here is link**: http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#vertical-stripes

So all you need to do is change following code to match your needs.

```
background-color: gray;
background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,.5) 50%);
background-size: 50px 50px;
```

Its better than writing css for each column.

For example this code is based on your data (with borders on left and right side)

**UPDATE** now no borders, only CSS!
used 2 gradients one for border stripes and another for repeating stripes. Removed percentage. Now it does the magic!

```
background-color: #111111;
background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 40px, #444444 20px ),
linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 940px, #222222 10px); 
background-size: 60px, 950px;
background-position: 10px, 10px;
```

Updated [jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/A3Z2L/1/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This wont help as the stripes can be different widths. This only allows for one x value.

Comment: Update your question. You did not mentioned that before.

Comment: I posted an image, that had different widths, I also posted two different variables, also different widths, I'm sorry but you didn't read the whole thing properly

Comment: If you only mean one wider and one shorter stripe (not every one different width), then just edit css and you are there! for example want to have 40px dark green followed by 10px light green just simply set size to `50px 50px` and change gradient percentages to `80%`. CSS3 is really powerful.

Comment: It needs to be dynamic and in percentages buddy

Comment: Im not getting this. You have 2 stripes, one shorter one wider. You are setting container width to fixed width and entering also number of stripes you want. So based on user input update CSS width to `GutterWidth + ColumnWidth` and set percentages as needed to `(100*ColumnWidth)/(GutterWidth + ColumnWidth)` Nothing more needed. Also if you have fixed width and fixed column size you dont need column count.

Comment: Alll of what you just said is irrelevant,  as I said its completely dynamic, I do need a column count so I can itterate over the columns to create the grwdient.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33123/discussion-between-shannon-hochkins-and-majky)

Comment: I also need the column widths to be a peecentage so that they can resize fluently with the container.

Comment: Hey, I answered my own question :) Maybe have a look :)

Comment: You sir, are a css genius :) Marked this is the correct answer! While my answer did have a very similar result, mine is so far elaborate it's not funny compared to yours, brilliant stuff. Not only that but you'rs will be much faster and less file size. Winning all round! Now I just have to write a function to automate this :( I'll update your answer once I do so people can use this awesome script :)

Comment: if you're intrested @Majky, here's the finished product! http://www.sassygrids.com

Comment: Interesting...maybe ill use it one day :)